# Has anyone been able to use a graph database with siddhi CEP?

Tags: graph, wso2, siddhi

Has anyone used a Graph database with Siddhi CEP (WSO2 Streaming integrator). I am looking for a way to ingest events from Kafka, and then use a graph topology to apply correlations.
Thanks for any pointers.

Regards
Srikanth

Comment: Could you please further explain the functionality needed? May be explain using a sample input event or events?

Comment: Hi, I am looking for a correlation using network topology. I have a use case with many network Sites (S1, S2, S3, S4,....S1000). Each of these sites have a lot of equipments (EQPT1, EQPT2, EQPT3,...). Further, each equipment has a certain number of cards (C1, C2, C3,...C100). My requirement is the following:  If a total of 4 cards in a site are down (during a timewindow of 10 minutes), then I need to send an alert.